# In Avro schema, how to specify conditional enum?

Tags: enums, avro

Is it possible in Avro schema definition to specify an enum which depends on the value of another enum.
Suppose you have category A with subcategories x1,x2,x3 and category B with y1,y2. In that case, how to validate that the json only contains valid combinations. 
E.g.

```
{"category":"A", "subcategory":"x1"}
```

is valid, but

```
{"category":"B", "subcategory":"y1"}
```

is not valid.

Comment: Can you change A and B to record types which have their respective enum subcategories?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Do you mean creating a separate record for each category?

Comment: Two Avro record containers with an `enum` field called `subcategory`